# Trying to copy merged cells from one sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that creates a new file, names it and copies data from a template. The problem I am having is getting all of the formatting over such as merged cells. Here is the code I have so far.

```
function createNewSheet(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  var name = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).getValue();
  var crNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("Job Traveler-" + name);
  var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(crNew.getUrl()).getId();
  importRange("1X4iOzc_shcOR8UM7OEM4F1-eR62YZmwKWyyEuu59Pf4","Job!A1:D", ssNew,"Sheet1!A1");
  copiedFormat();

}

function importRange(sourceId,sourceRange,destinationID,destinationRangeStart){

  const sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceId);
  const sourceRng = sourceSS.getRange(sourceRange);
  const sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues();

  // Get formatting data
  const sourceFontStyle = sourceRng.getFontStyles();
  const sourceFontWeight = sourceRng.getFontWeights();
  const sourceFontBackgroundColor = sourceRng.getBackgrounds();

  const destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID);
  const destStartRange = destinationSS.getRange(destinationRangeStart);
  const destSheet = destinationSS.getSheetByName(destStartRange.getSheet().getName());

  destSheet.clear();

  const destRange = destSheet.getRange(
    destStartRange.getRow(),
    destStartRange.getColumn(),
    sourceVals.length,
    sourceVals[0].length
  );

  destRange.setValues(sourceVals);

   // Set formatting
  destRange.setFontStyles(sourceFontStyle);
  destRange.setFontWeights(sourceFontWeight);
  destRange.setBackgrounds(sourceFontBackgroundColor);

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
}
```

Best

Comment: You can copy the entire sheet to the new spreadsheet then use copyTo with formating to copy the data to desired sheets then delete the newly created sheet.

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

I've only provided the addtional steps to duplicate merged cells from one range to another.  I leave it to you to incorporate the relavent code to your script.  I've included a debugging step 'merged.forEach()' which you can remove for production.

**Script**

```
function createNewSheet() {
  try {
    // in my case source and destination are the same spreadsheet but different sheets
    // and I have made the ranges arbitrary
    importRange("Sheet5","Sheet5!C6:L11","Sheet6","Sheet6!E11")
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

function importRange(sourceId,sourceRange,destinationID,destinationRangeStart) {
  try {
    var sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sourceRng = sourceSS.getRange(sourceRange);
    var sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues();

    var destinationSS = sourceSS;
    var destStartRange = destinationSS.getRange(destinationRangeStart);
    var destSheet = destinationSS.getSheetByName(destStartRange.getSheet().getName());
    var row = destStartRange.getRow();
    var col = destStartRange.getColumn();
    var rows = sourceVals.length;
    var cols = sourceVals[0].length;
    destSheet.getRange(row,col,rows,cols).setValues(sourceVals);

    var merged = sourceRng.getMergedRanges();
    merged.forEach( range => console.log(range.getA1Notation()));
    var rowOffset = destStartRange.getRow()-sourceRng.getRow();
    var columnOffset = destStartRange.getColumn()-sourceRng.getColumn();
    for( var i=0; i<merged.length; i++ ) {
      row = merged[i].getRow()+rowOffset;
      col = merged[i].getColumn()+columnOffset;
      rows = merged[i].getNumRows();
      cols = merged[i].getNumColumns();
      destSheet.getRange(row,col,rows,cols).merge();
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getMergedRanges()
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#merge()